# Reledmac multiple hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, reledmac

Is there a way to specify multiple hyphenation exception list in a multi-lingual document where is also a reledmac environment?
In a parallel section of the file the french word "conçue" is divided in "co-nçue" which is awful. But "con-çue" is even worst, so that word is a mono syllable word. I tried to correct by means the code suggested by egreg in "specifying multiple hyphenation ...." but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: formally, reledmac has no influence on hyphen. i.e : if an hyphen rule works / does not work with "normal" TeX, it works / does not works with reledmac.

Comment: Is really “conçue“ monosyllabic? I don't think so.

Comment: If I check using `\showhyphens{conçue}` with `polyglossia` set to French I get "conçue" shown as unhyphenated. "co-nçue" only appears when I set it to Italian. Did you possibly forget to switch the language to French?

Answer (score 1):

`\hyphenation{conçue}` or `\hyphenation{conçue-}` means that there are no allowed places of hyphenation.

Comment: I don't think `\-` is a valid token in `\hyphenation`.

Comment: @egreg From this site conçue seems to be monosyllabic http://www.separarensilabas.com/index-fr.php

Answer (score 1):

For `reledpar` languages/hyphenation-rules have to be switched like in every other document, i.e. at least within every `Leftside`/`Rightside`-environment when typesetting different languages. Use the usual commands from `polyglossia` for xelatex and `babel` for pdflatex respectively.

Exceptions to hyphenations have to be set *while the language in question is active*.

Cf. this xelatex-example, adapted from the `reledmac` example files:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
%define exceptions here:
\hyphenation{}

\selectlanguage{french}
\showhyphens{conçue}
%\hyphenation{conçue} %obviously not necessary?

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \selectlanguage{french}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
La philologie consiste en l'étude d'un langage à partir de documents écrits. C'est une combinaison de critique littéraire, historique et linguistique.
            \pend
            \pstart
Elle vise à rétablir le contenu original de textes connus par plusieurs sources, c’est-à-dire à sélectionner le texte le plus authentique possible, à partir de manuscrits, d'éditions imprimées ou d'autres sources disponibles (citations par d’autres auteurs, voire graffiti anciens), en comparant les versions conservées de ces textes, ou à rétablir le meilleur texte en corrigeant les sources existantes.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \selectlanguage{english}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
Philology is the study of language in written historical sources; it is a combination of literary criticism, history, and linguistics.
            \pend
            \pstart
It is more commonly defined as the study of literary texts and written records, the establishment of their authenticity and their original form, and the determination of their meaning. A person who pursues this kind of study is known as a philologist.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\end{document}
```